# Generating random samples from a density function

Tags: algorithms, random-generation, density-function

How does a computer algorithm set up to take as input an arbirary bivariate probability density function, generate pairs of numbers from that distribution? I have found a routine called simcontour that is part of LearnBayes in R that performs that operation.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling

Answer (score 6):

Denote the joint density you want to sample from by $p_{XY}(x,y)$. Then the marginal densities are easily obtainable:

$$ p_{X}(x) = \int_{D_{Y}} p_{XY}(x,y) dy, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ p_{Y}(y) = \int_{D_{X}} p_{XY}(x,y) dx $$

where $D_X, D_Y$ denote the support of $X, Y$, respectively. From this you can calculate each of the conditional density functions:

$$ p_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{ p_{XY}(x,y) }{ p_{Y}(y) }, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ p_{Y|X=x}(y) = \frac{ p_{XY}(x,y) }{ p_{X}(x) } $$

From here you can execute Gibbs' sampling to sample from $p_{XY}$. That is, start with some arbitrary starting value in the $(x_{0}, y_{0})$. Then, at step $i$,

**(1)** Sample from $p_{X|Y=y_{i}}(x)$ to obtain $x_{i+1}$

**(2)** Sample from $p_{Y|X=x_{i+1}}(y)$ to obtain $y_{i+1}$

**(3)** Repeat a number of times equal to the desired sample size

Each $(x_{i}, y_{i})$ is an approximate draw from the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. The conditional densities can be sampled from in steps **(1)** and **(2)** using, for example, rejection sampling assuming they do not come from one of the "standard" distributions, in which case you can use a pre-existing function to generate from them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use rejection sampling.
Let $f$ be the probability density we want to sample from 
(it does not matter if it is 1- or 2-dimensional).
If we can find a probability distribution $g$, 
from which we can easily sample from,
e.g., a uniform distribution (a good choice, if the support of $f$ is bounded),
a Gaussian distribution,
or a Cauchy distribution (a last-resort choice, inefficient but useful if $f$ has fat tails),
such that there exists a constant $c$ with $f \leq c g$,
then we can sample from $f$ as follows.
Take a random sample $x$ from $g$, take a random number $\lambda$ uniformly in $[0,1]$;
if $\lambda c g(x) < f(x)$, keep the sample, otherwise reject it and try again. 
Repeat until you have the desired number of samples.

The reason why it works is easily seen on a picture: $(x,\lambda c g(x))$ is a point sampled uniformly in the area under the curve $x \mapsto c g(x)$, and the condition $\lambda c g(x) < f(x)$ asks that it be under the curve $x\mapsto f(x)$.